# Question about the literary device personification

Tags: literary-device, personification

But what I miss,
Among these mahua trees,
When merrily I pace,
Is the beholding pleasure
Of her face.

This is a stanza from a poem.I would like to know if 'beholding pleasure'could be an example of personification or it is incorrect.

Comment: Is what incorrect?

Comment: Why do you think it's personification? Without further context, it sounds like the narrator is describing a real woman (or girl), in which case it would not be personification.